# JavaEE JTA UserTransaction insert data to multiple tables

Tags: mysql, jpa, jakarta-ee, jboss, foreign-keys

How I can insert data to multiple tables (MySQL) in `Java EE&JBoss7.1`. I did a couple of simple tutorials but now I have one table and a file where I added my data and from this file method which added data was called from EntityManager. Now I want to use many tables with relations. I add a simple example of what I want to make.

[Structure tables](http://www73.zippyshare.com/v/48459839/file.html)

My tables (class) which was generated by using JPA 2.0.

User.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    private String password;

    //bi-directional one-to-one association to Profile
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="user")
    private Profile profile;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to UserRole
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles;

    //bi-directional many-to-many association to Activity
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name="user_activity"
        , joinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="users_id")
            }
        , inverseJoinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="activities_id")
            }
        )
    private Set<Activity> activities;

    public User() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Profile getProfile() {
        return this.profile;
    }

    public void setProfile(Profile profile) {
        this.profile = profile;
    }

    public Set<UserRole> getUserRoles() {
        return this.userRoles;
    }

    public void setUserRoles(Set<UserRole> userRoles) {
        this.userRoles = userRoles;
    }

    public Set<Activity> getActivities() {
        return this.activities;
    }

    public void setActivities(Set<Activity> activities) {
        this.activities = activities;
    }

}
```

UserRole.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_roles")
public class UserRole implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private UserRolePK id;

    private String name;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to User
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="users_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private User user;

    public UserRole() {
    }

    public UserRolePK getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(UserRolePK id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

}
```

UserRolePK.java:

```
@Embeddable
public class UserRolePK implements Serializable {
    //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="users_id")
    private int usersId;

    @Column(name="role_name")
    private String roleName;

    public UserRolePK() {
    }
    public int getUsersId() {
        return this.usersId;
    }
    public void setUsersId(int usersId) {
        this.usersId = usersId;
    }
    public String getRoleName() {
        return this.roleName;
    }
    public void setRoleName(String roleName) {
        this.roleName = roleName;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (this == other) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(other instanceof UserRolePK)) {
            return false;
        }
        UserRolePK castOther = (UserRolePK)other;
        return 
            (this.usersId == castOther.usersId)
            && this.roleName.equals(castOther.roleName);

    }

    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int hash = 17;
        hash = hash * prime + this.usersId;
        hash = hash * prime + this.roleName.hashCode();

        return hash;
    }
}
```

Data are inserted into "User" but rest is doesn't work.

I wrote this:

```
@ManagedBean(name="bean")
//@SessionScoped
//@LocalBean

public class RegistrationBean implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3158649307217736396L;
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


        public String name;
        public String password;
        public int id;

        public int usersId = id;
        public String roleName="user";

        public Set<UserRole> userRoles;


        @EJB
        private UserService us;

        public int getUsersId() {
            return usersId;
        }

        public void setUsersId(int usersId) {
            this.usersId = usersId;
        }

        public String getRoleName() {
            return roleName;
        }

        public void setRoleName(String roleName) {
            this.roleName = roleName;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String addUser() {
            User u = new User();
            UserRolePK urpk = new UserRolePK();
            UserRole ur = new UserRole();
            u.setName(name);
            u.setPassword(password);
            u.setId(id);

            urpk.setUsersId(usersId);
            urpk.setRoleName(roleName);

            ur.setName(name);
            ur.setUser(u);

            us.addUser(u);
            us.addUser(urpk);
            us.addUser(ur);
            return "registerbean";

        }
}
```

and:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
//@ManagedBean
public  class UserService implements UserServiceInterface {



    @PersistenceContext(unitName="virtual.trainer.library")
    private EntityManager em;


    public UserService() {

    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return em.createQuery("FROM User").getResultList();
    }

    public void addUser(User u) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        em.persist(u);
    }


    public void addUser(UserRolePK urpk) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        em.persist(urpk);
    }


    public void addPK(UserRolePK urpk) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        em.persist(urpk);
    }


    public void addUser(UserRole ur) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        em.persist(ur);
    }


}
```

okay, I made 'UserTransaction' JTA but still I have problems:

```
@ManagedBean(name="bean")
//@SessionScoped
//@LocalBean

public class RegistrationBean implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3158649307217736396L;

    //u
        public String name;
        public String password;
        public Set<UserRole> userRoles;
    //ur
        public UserRolePK id;
        public User user;
    //urpk
        public String roleName="user";
        public int usersId;

        @EJB
        private UserService us;

        //--- getter, setter

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

        public Set<UserRole> getUserRoles() {
            return userRoles;
        }

        public void setUserRoles(Set<UserRole> userRoles) {
            this.userRoles = userRoles;
        }

        public UserRolePK getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(UserRolePK id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public User getUser() {
            return user;
        }

        public void setUser(User user) {
            this.user = user;
        }

        public String getRoleName() {
            return roleName;
        }

        public void setRoleName(String roleName) {
            this.roleName = roleName;
        }

        public int getUsersId() {
            return usersId;
        }

        public void setUsersId(int usersId) {
            this.usersId = usersId;
        }




        public String addUser()  {

            User u = new User();
            UserRole ur = new UserRole();
            UserRolePK urpk = new UserRolePK();

            u.setName(name);
            u.setPassword(password);
            u.setUserRoles(userRoles);


            ur.setName(name);
            ur.setUser(user);
            ur.setId(urpk);

            urpk.setRoleName(roleName);
            urpk.setUsersId(usersId);

            us.addUser(u, ur);

            return "adduser";
        }
}
```

UserService.java:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public  class UserService implements UserServiceInterface {


    @PersistenceContext(unitName="virtual.trainer.entities", type=PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
    private EntityManager em;

    @Resource
    @ Inject
    private UserTransaction xtx ;

    public UserService() {

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<User> getUsers() {
//      return null;
        return em.createQuery("FROM User").getResultList();
    }


    public void addUser(User u, UserRole ur)  {



            try {
                xtx.begin();
                em.persist(u);
                em.persist(ur);
                xtx.commit();
            } catch (NotSupportedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Chujnia z grzybnia1/7");
            } catch (SystemException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Chujnia z grzybnia2/7");
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Chujnia z grzybnia3/7");
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Chujnia z grzybnia4/7");
            } catch (RollbackException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Chujnia z grzybnia5/7");
            } catch (HeuristicMixedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Chujnia z grzybnia6/7");
            } catch (HeuristicRollbackException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Chujnia z grzybnia7/7");
            }

//          em.persist(urpk);

            em.flush();
//          em.close();

    }

}
```

Console:

```
07:28:53,476 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) javax.transaction.NotSupportedException: BaseTransaction.checkTransactionState - ARJUNA016051: thread is already associated with a transaction!

07:28:53,478 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.begin(BaseTransaction.java:63)

07:28:53,479 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.begin(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:65)

07:28:53,480 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.tm.usertx.client.ServerVMClientUserTransaction.begin(ServerVMClientUserTransaction.java:142)

07:28:53,481 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at virtual.trainer.bean.UserService.addUser(UserService.java:66)

07:28:53,482 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

07:28:53,483 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

07:28:53,484 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

07:28:53,484 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

07:28:53,485 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory.java:72)

07:28:53,486 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

07:28:53,487 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)

07:28:53,488 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:36)

07:28:53,489 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

07:28:53,490 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)

07:28:53,491 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

07:28:53,492 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)

07:28:53,493 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

07:28:53,494 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)

07:28:53,495 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53)

07:28:53,496 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

07:28:53,497 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)

07:28:53,498 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

07:28:53,499 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:228)

07:28:53,499 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:304)

07:28:53,500 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190)

07:28:53,501 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

07:28:53,502 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)

07:28:53,503 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

07:28:53,504 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59)

07:28:53,505 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

07:28:53,506 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)

07:28:53,507 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

07:28:53,508 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:32)

07:28:53,509 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

07:28:53,510 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45)

07:28:53,511 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

07:28:53,511 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)

07:28:53,512 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165)

07:28:53,513 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:173)

07:28:53,514 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

07:28:53,515 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)

07:28:53,516 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:72)

07:28:53,517 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at virtual.trainer.bean.UserService$$$view297.addUser(Unknown Source)

07:28:53,517 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at pl.wlukasiak.beans.RegistrationBean.addUser(RegistrationBean.java:120)

07:28:53,518 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

07:28:53,519 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

07:28:53,520 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

07:28:53,521 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

07:28:53,521 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:262)

07:28:53,522 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)

07:28:53,523 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)

07:28:53,524 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)

07:28:53,525 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)

07:28:53,526 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)

07:28:53,527 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)

07:28:53,527 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)

07:28:53,528 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)

07:28:53,529 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)

07:28:53,530 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)

07:28:53,531 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)

07:28:53,532 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)

07:28:53,533 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)

07:28:53,533 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)

07:28:53,534 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)

07:28:53,535 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:397)

07:28:53,536 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)

07:28:53,537 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)

07:28:53,538 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)

07:28:53,539 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)

07:28:53,540 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)

07:28:53,541 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)

07:28:53,542 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)

07:28:53,542 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)

07:28:53,543 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)

07:28:53,544 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

07:28:53,545 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: BaseTransaction.checkTransactionState - ARJUNA016051: thread is already associated with a transaction!

07:28:53,546 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.checkTransactionState(BaseTransaction.java:257)

07:28:53,547 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.begin(BaseTransaction.java:59)

07:28:53,548 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   ... 74 more

07:28:53,549 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Chujnia z grzybnia1/7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't update two tables at once.

You can although create a data base procedure to do it by passing the vars to the proc.

Using Transactions you can check the results of an update and go forward to the next update.
If one fails you can rollback and no changes will take place.

MySql supports this but you need to use the correct settings and database [ InnoDB ].

START TRANSACTION;
Update table one set x = bla;
if error rollback else
Update table two set y = bla;
if error rollback else commit;

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

The example is not code - just an example

You can write this in Java or better - avoid Java and write a proc
.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html

Comment: What i want, generally, i need write in java ee adding user, so name, password in user table and in UserRole table: name, user role, user_id which is the the same like id in user table, but i dont understand relation beetwen this class.